# SQL - select for each user the total articles and the total article comments

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get for each user the total number of articles and for each article the total number of comments, something like this:

```
username | total_articles | total_comments
John Doe |      3         |    10
```

This is my SQL until now, I am using MySQL:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, COUNT(a.id) AS total_articles, COUNT(c.id) AS total_comments FROM users u
LEFT JOIN articles a ON u.id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN comments c ON a.id = c.article_id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

I tried to group by `u.id`, `a.id`, `c.id` at the same time but it's not working correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: It's just my guess: you need `COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)` instead of just `COUNT`

Comment: GROUP BY u.id, u.username;

Comment: I think DISTINCT it's only for distinct records, my records are already distinct because I use primary keys.

Comment: Still not working, the result is giving me wrong values for total_articles and total_comments.Thank you!

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're getting for them?

Comment: Sure, this is the live fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qXDW3qFgZSuE3txBBxRHp8/0 I am just trying to learn more about SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first query there are all the articles by user, in the second all the comments joined by user

> edited: use LEFT JOIN insted JOIN

```
SELECT id_total_articles, username, total_articles, total_comments 
              FROM 
                  (
                    SELECT u.id as id_total_articles, u.username, COUNT(a.id) AS total_articles FROM users u
                    LEFT JOIN articles a ON u.id = a.user_id
                    GROUP BY u.id, u.username
                ) as  AC 
                 left join 
                (
                  SELECT u.id as id_total_comments, COUNT(c.id) AS total_comments FROM users u
                  LEFT JOIN comments c ON u.id = c.user_id
                  GROUP BY u.id, u.username 
                ) as  CC 
            ON AC.id_total_articles = CC.id_total_comments;
```

Comment: check edit, use left join because if a user does't have comments and articles he will not be displayed

Comment: I noticed that thing but I was happy with the answer, not, everything is just PERFECT, thank you! I am learning more about SQL so I am trying different things, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use `u.id, u.username` both column in group by

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, COUNT(a.id) AS total_articles,
 COUNT(c.id) AS total_comments FROM users u
LEFT JOIN articles a ON u.id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN comments c ON a.id = c.article_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `u.username` in the `group by`, also `COUNT(a.id)` must change into `COUNT(distinct a.id)`:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, COUNT(distinct a.id) AS total_articles, COUNT(c.id) AS total_comments FROM users u
LEFT JOIN articles a ON u.id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN comments c ON a.id = c.article_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username;
```

## Update:

However, I guess that what you actually need is something other than your proposed query. You said that you need **the total number of articles for each user** and **the total number of comment for each article**. That means you need two separate queries:

```
SELECT a.id article_id , COUNT(c.id) AS total_comments
FROM articles a 
LEFT JOIN comments c ON a.id = c.article_id
GROUP BY a.id

SELECT u.id, u.username, COUNT(distinct a.id) AS total_articles
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN articles a ON u.id = a.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username;
```

Comment: Just one article has comments but the result is telling me there is another article who has one comment ( not correct ).Thanks!

Comment: In the fiddle, there are two comments for article number 2 and one comment for article number 1.

Comment: I updated the answer, check if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Someone gave the correct answer, check it above, that's what I desired to achieve.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are aggregating along related dimensions and getting overcounting.

One approach is to use multiple aggregations:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, COUNT(a.id) AS total_articles,
       SUM(c.num_comments) AS total_comments
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     articles a
     ON a.user_id = a.id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.article_id, COUNT(c.id) as num_comments
      FROM comments c
      GROUP BY c.article_id
     ) c
     ON a.id = c.article_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username;
```

Comment: I tried your version, it's not woring, but thanks for giving more ideas.

Comment: @MeOnly . . . Other than miscounting the `0` values (which is now fixed), are there any other problems?

Comment: Your answer is giving me 0 when it comes to counting, check the answer above, someone got it right, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the number of articles for a user, and the total number of comments on all the articles of the user - then this is your query:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.username,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) AS total_articles,
    COUNT(c.id) AS total_comments
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN articles a 
    ON u.id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN comments c 
    ON a.id = c.article_id
GROUP BY
    u.id,
    u.username;
```

But - if you are looking for the number of comments (just a thought here) of the **user** - then you want to join the comments table on the user id, and not the article id.

Comment: I want to show the number of articles written by every user and for every article I want to show the total number of comments made on that article by everybody.I am just trying to learn more of SQL and I had this idea in mind..

Comment: I checked the results of my query in the db-fiddle. And they are correct. Perhaps you can try to explain again, what it is that you want to see in the results table from the query?

Comment: Someone gave me the correct answer, check it above, that was my desired result.